# Suppose I am AWS IAM user, is there any way so that I can check what resource permission has been given to me using CLI or Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam, bucket

Suppose, I am AWS IAM user, ***is there any way so that I can check what resource permission has been given to me,*** using CLI or Console.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is **no comprehensive tool for that**. In IAM console you can only check your user's IAM profile or group permission you belong to.

But full set of privileges is a very complex thing to get. Apart from obvious IAM user or group permissions you can have:

- IAM roles which you can assume,
- resource policies which you are listed as a principle (e.g. bucket policy, kms key policy),
- resource policies where a role you can assume is a principle,
- cross-account permissions in IAM roles or resource policies,
- AWS Organization level SCP permissions.

If the reason for asking this question is related to security, e.g., to check what resources were accessed by a compromised IAM user credentials, you suspend the credentials or delete the user. Also can inspect the **CloudTrial** history to check what resources a given IAM user accessed.